# How to get timezone offset from Time.now

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
Time.now   #=> 2007-11-19 08:27:30 -0600
```

I want get timezone offset **+0600** from Time.now. A Native ruby function is welcome if it exist.

What i tried :

```
Time.now.to_s.byteslice(-5..-1) #=> "-0600" as String
```

It works for my timezone(GET+1) but I want to find a better way.

Comment: Note: `Time.now.to_s.byteslice(-3)` only works for positive Timezone numbers between 0 and 9.

Comment: If your timezone was `+1200`, would you expect `2` or `12`? And what's the expected result for `+05:45`? `5` (truncated), `6` (rounded) or `5.75` (its decimal representation)

Comment: If my timezone was `+1200`, I want get `12`.

Comment: @孙悟空 And if your timezone was `-1200`, do you want `12` as well or `-12`?

Comment: @Stefan In this case, I perfer `-12`, I saw that the funciton `strftime('%:z')` return a number and sens(+ or -) as well. that's what I'm looking for. Thank you.

Comment: `strftime('%:z')` returns the _string_ `"-12:00"`, not a number.

Comment: The english you are looking for is "timezone offset". The offset is how many hours the timezone is off, negative or positive, from UTC. While it is a whole number, it is normally expressed in the "06:00" format.

Comment: Plenty of places use a 30 minute timezone offset. Relying on a whole number is folly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use it

```
Time.now.strftime('%z')
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. it point me to find my final answer : `Time.now.strftime('%:z')`.

Comment: `%:z - hour and minute offset from UTC with a colon (e.g. +09:00)`

Comment: `%::z - hour, minute and second offset from UTC (e.g. +09:00:00)`